# IIS no longer working after Export configuration

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2019

After following some instructions to Export Configuration from a 2008 server, IIS 7 to a 2019 server, IIS10 IIS on the 2019 server no longer works.
It's pointing at the 'Import' folder, which is where I placed the config files exported from the 2008 server.
I don't know how to reset the IIS 10 instance to just be a clean, normal edition and start from fresh.

I currently receive the message:

> Failed to connect
> Filename: ...Config\Import\administration.config'...
> Error: The configuration section 'moduleProviders' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration.

I want it to be looking at ...Config, not ...Config\Import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Disabling the IIS Shared Config did the trick
Powershell:

```
C:\> Disable-IISSharedConfig
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/disable-iissharedconfig?view=windowsserver2022-ps